# Invalid Language Name detected on browser

Tags: c#, browser, cultureinfo

I got this code to retrieve the browser language that was set by the user:

```
string cultureName = string.Empty;

try
{
    string[] languages = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;
    cultureName = languages[0].ToLowerInvariant().Trim();
}
catch
{
    cultureName = "en-US";
}

System.Globalization.CultureInfo browserCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = browserCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = browserCulture;
```

I got these errors:

1. `Culture name 'name' is not supported`: From our error logs, found out that name is `x-ns1xs4m8wixnxg`, `x-ns1dfk__jmpnx0` etc.. I do not know where this languages come from, or what are they, but I think these languages are retrieved when browsing from mobile.
2. `The name 'name' contains characters that are not valid for a Culture or Region`: Also found out that name is `fr; q=1.0`, `en;q=1.0`, `en_us`, `en;q=0.9`, etc... I'm thinking that I should parse it per character to see if it is a valid

I have already modified my code to handle these errors:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo;

try
{
    string[] languages = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;
    string cultureName = languages[0].ToLowerInvariant().Trim();
    cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);
}
catch
{
    cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
}

System.Globalization.CultureInfo browserCulture = cultureInfo;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = browserCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = browserCulture;
```

but I would like to know where these languages came from, or how to replicate them? This is to verify if my code is working properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you should be aware of that `UserLanguages` will simply return corresponding HTTP header. Header values may have additional attributes separated by `;`. So you should split that value on `;` and get the first bit.

As for `x-ns1dfk__jmpnx0` I would say ignore it. Falling back to your default language in this case is totally valid.

edit: I take the first part back. According to [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) the q parameter is the value of the language preference. So what you really should do is split on semicolon, then parse value of q attribute (assume 1 if not present), then sort on it and take the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll note on this one. BTW, beside from `fr; q=1.0` languages, sometimes I retrieve languages like `en_us` which generates `error 2`, looks like parsing `;` is not my option

Comment: just to verify this one: "_So you should split that value on_ `;` _and get the first bit._", I know this way will work, but how sure are we, that the `language` will always be in the first bit? And regards with the formatting, will I always retrieve `header values` with `;` as attribute separator? Thanks :)

Comment: We are absolutely positive. The first bit is the actual header value. Everything after is attributes.